# What time will a steam game unlock for me?

Tags: steam

So basically i'm thinking of pre-ordering fallout 4, and i was just wondering at what time would it come out for me if i did get it. Recently gamestop told me if i pre-ordered with them that they can release the game at 9:00 PM (West Coast PST)
instead of 12 anymore. Does that same thing go for Steam as well?

Comment: This question gives you the answer you're looking for: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/18009/steam-available-on-date-vs-unlock-in-countdown

Comment: Gamestop can only sell you a box with a DVD containing part(!) of the game files and **a steam key**, meaning that the steam unlock time will be paramount. Gamestop selling you the box earlier might allot you time to install the game.

Comment: In this case i failed to mention that gamestop was going to sell me the xbox one version of the game at 9pm, i did this with the Halo 5 release and got to play it at 9:20 when everything was installed

Answer (score 3):

Games on Steam generally unlock at 10am US Pacific time on the day of release.

So, depending on the time of year, either 10am PST (-0800) or 10am PDT (-0700).

Comment: Thanks for the fast response! and yeah i pre-ordered and its starting show the time on steam. Still thanks for the response!